# How to Implement Dependency Inversion and Interface Segregation for a Concrete Class that Needs to Be Initiated?

Tags: python, oop, solid-principles, dependency-inversion, interface-segregation-principle

##### Context

So far as I understand, the Dependency Inversion and Interface Segregation principles of SOLID OOP tell us to write our program according to the *interface*, not internal details. So, I am trying to develop a simple stock-market data collector in Python, roughly with the following object diagram, where `main` encapsulates the application business logic, user input handling etc. Here is how to make sense of it

- Pink represents concrete function or class, green represents an abstract class
- Hollow arrow head represents a subclass of/implements relationship, and solid arrow head represents a *using* relationship (following the convention of *Clean Architecture* by Robert Martin)

[image: Object diagram of stock price reader]

So the main function uses the abstract interface which fetches a stock price against a symbol. The abstract class looks like

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

"""
Defines the abstract stock price reader
"""
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class StockPriceReader(ABC):
    """Defines the general tick reader interface."""
    @abstractmethod
    def get_price(self, symbol:str)->float:
        """
        Gets the price of a stock represented by the symbol, e.g 
        when symbol='AAPL', it gets the Apple Inc stock price. 
        """
        raise NotImplementedError
```

The `TickReaderConcrete` class implements the internal details, and gets the actual stock price by something like a Bloomberg or trading exchange API call. The credentials necessary to make the API call have to be part of the internal details. Not showing the code here, as it is pretty simple to implement.

##### Dilemma

Now, based on the above simple class dependency diagram, the same book (*Clean Architecture*) seems to imply that (here I emphasise)

> The main block should *not even be aware* that the TickReaderConcrete exists.

At least, that is my understanding of what the book is saying, as there is no arrow head from `main` to the `TickReaderConcrete`, correct me if I am wrong.

But when I write the `main.py` I cannot pretend that `TickReaderConcrete` does not exist, in other words, seems `main` cannot help but know about the existence of `TickReaderConcrete` when the code looks like

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

"""
The main function to invoke the stockprice reader
"""
from tickreader import TickReaderConcrete
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This line gives rise to the alternative class diagram below
    reader=TickReaderConcrete(...) 

    # After initialised, we can use the interface permitted by the abstract base class
    reader.get_price(symbol='IBM')
```

###### Question

So how to make sure the `main` is unaware of the concrete reader's existence? If `main` does not import the concrete reader at all, it cannot even instantiate the concrete reader object, and the abstract reader cannot be initialised anyway.
So how to basically organise the code to properly implement the object diagram above?

###### Slightly Paraphrased Question

Even if the abstract base class exposes the necessary public methods, at the very least, the *initialisation* requires knowledge of the existence of concrete subclass. Can the concrete subclass hide behind the abstract base class? Look at the alternative object diagram, which is what is implemented by the above code snippet. How to get rid of the broken line?

[image]

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/9501604/126014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been some years since I read Clean Architecture, but I'd like to suggest a variant interpretation. The [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (DIP) does, indeed, suggest that that abstractions shouldn't depend on implementation details, but rather the other way around.

Defining a high-level interface or abstract base class and implementing it with a concrete class that contains all the details is a standard approach to address such concerns.

The DIP then suggests that almost all of your code should be written against the high-level abstraction. This means that if you have domain logic that needs to call the `get_price` method, it should be given a `StockPriceReader` abstract object to interact with.

There is, however, one exception to that rule, because [you need to compose the object graphs somewhere](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot), and that's usually in the `__main__` method. This is where you create an instance of the concrete class, and then pass it to all the other code that expects the abstract class.

Comment: So you mean the the DIP violation I am facing with, is part of the acceptable exception to the rule?

Comment: @Della Yes. I did a quick look-up in Clean Architecture, and it says something similar in the subsection called *Concrete Components* in chapter 11 on the DIP: *"DIP violations cannot be entirely removed, but they can be gathered into a small number of concrete components and kept separate from the rest of the system. Most systems will contain at least one such concrete component—often called `main` because it contains the `main` function."*.